# Is it possible to do a password less signIn & signOut with amplify_auth_cognito in flutter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to do a **password less signIn & signOut** in flutter with amplify, but I don't see an option on the **[amplify_auth_cognito](https://pub.dev/packages/amplify_auth_cognito)** package (that aws provides in pub.dev) that allows or hints me how to do it, is it even possible to do it with this package or should I use some other package? if **yes** then which one and how to do it?

The user pool that I'm using is from an actual working web application which I imported following the [aws flutter documentaion](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/import/)

Thank you in advance.

What I experimented with was the default methods provided by **amplify_auth_cognito** as shown below:

```
      var signUpConfirmedd = await auth.signUp(
        username: _email,
        // tried not filling the password field but it doesn't work
        password: '1234567890',
        options: CognitoSignUpOptions(
          userAttributes: {
            CognitoUserAttributeKey.email: _email,
            CognitoUserAttributeKey.name: 'nityy'
          },
        ),
      );
```

Comment: did you figured out how ? im facing the same problem

Comment: @Oku try using the beta version for the package as stated here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/2259 it will work